# JavaScript Global mouse hook

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Hello i have a web based slideshow, which is basically an amount of pages that is called using a timer.

The customer now wants a silverlight/flash game in a slide and only activate it when the screen is touched (touch screen). This means that i need to capture ANY mouse activity in a javascript and then have my Javascript call a different page (containing the silverlight/flash). The problem as i see it is that the slide can be anything: images, video, youtube, HTML...you name it...if it can run in a browser i need to intercept any mouse input/touch.

Is this even possible?

My first thought is to make a 100% transparent <div> tag and place it above everything and have that contain the onclick event....

any help is appreciated

**Solution**
After having researched a bit i found out it cant be done. But - there is a workaround, make a <div> tag with a transparent images as background - make it fill the entire screen. Then attach a click event to that one, presto - all done:

```
<style>
    body, html
    {
        margin:0px;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }

    a
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        display: block;
    }

    a:hover
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        display: block;
        background-color:red;
    }

    #popover
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;        
        background-image:url('/gfx/transparent.png');
        z-index:999;
        position:absolute;
        left:0ox;
        top:0px;
    }

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popover").click(function () {
            alert('Clicked the popover screen');
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>
    Index</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Display" id="showbutton" />
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        <td> <a href="#">Test</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
</div>
<div id="popover">
</div>
```

Please note that the link boxes wont highlight when you click the button - and you get the click event. Hope it helps - i had a tough time figuring it out.

Comment: Be careful with a DIV overlaying everything to catch clicks like that. Browsers (or some security plugins) may consider this [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) and your website may be labeled malicious, even if you don't intend to be.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up RoTaRa. This program is made for a customer and it is up to them to decide now. Im not too worried though, the site is behind a login screen and not something available to the general public.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).bind("click", function() {
    alert("you clicked the page");
});
```

But you can't run Flash/Silverlight on iOS and Adobe dosn't support by Andoid anymore, don't know about Silverlight

Comment: Will this fire if i click within a flash/javascript element on my page - and can it intercept the click so it doesnt fire on the flash/silverlight element?